# Factorisation of repunits and determination whether a number is prime. Are these two questions linked?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-mathematics

Let $R(n)$ denote a repunit in decimal number system of $n$ digits. With the exception of $2,3$ and $5$ (which have easy divisibility tests), its factors can only be of two types:

1. Positive integers of the form $nm+1$ where $m$ is a
   natural number.
2. The divisors of $R(k)$, where $k$ is a factor of $n$.

(So for the first type of factors, the smallest factor of $R$(n) can be $n+1$ and the largest, the number itself.)

Firstly i wanted to ask is this a well established and documented result?

Secondly has this way of factoring a repunit been used in factoring a number or more importatnly in forming a primality testing algorithm?

Comment: Question adjusted based on the comments below Andreas' answer.

Comment: Ok thanks i guess

Comment: @EricStucky, thanks. The current is true, provided we are talking about *prime* factors. Of course $2$ and $5$ do not divide any repunit, unless we count $R(0) = 0$ as a repunit. Let $p \ne 3$ be a prime. Then if $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that  $p$ divides $R(n) = (10^{n} - 1)/(10 - 1)$, then $n$ is also the smallest positive integer such that $p$ divides $10^{n} - 1$, so $n$ is the period of $10$ modulo $p$, so $n$ divides $\varphi(p) = p-1$, so $p \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. And clearly $R(k)$ divides $R(n)$ iff $k$ divides $n$.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted my earlier answer, because it referred to a different formulation of the question, and also because in the ensuing discussion I think I may have understood what OP has in mind.

As stated **now**, the question appears to claim that the factors of a repunit
$$
R(n) = \frac{10^n - 1}{ 10 -1}
$$
are of one of the following form

- congruent to $1$ modulo $n$,
- repunits $R(k)$, with $k \mid n$,
- $3$.

This is of course not true, as $101$ divides $R(8)$, but does not fit in any category.

What is true is that if $p \ne 3$ is a prime divisor of $R(n)$, but not of any $R(k)$, with $k < n$, then $n$ is the period of $10$ modulo $p$, and thus $n$ divides $\varphi(p) = p - 1$, so that $p$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $n$.

Comment: The first and third conditions you have understood correctly. In the second condition u r missing a point. 101 divides R(4) so automatically that means it divides all repunits of the form R(j) where j is a multiple of 4 meaning 101 should divide R(8) R(12) and so on you get the point. This case is the same as R same as R(15)mhaving as its factor the number 41 because 41 divides R(5)

Comment: The point **you** are missing is that you are stating that *[i]ts factors can **only** be of two types*. Here you write two but you mean three. And then $101$ is not of one of the two (three) types. Words do have a precise meaning in Maths. Bye.

Comment: When i wrote other repunits R(k) then how can u factor those repunits and count them as a seperate type on numbers? I mean u r going to factorise R(4) R(8) and then u will say that these numbers divide R(16) and theses factors are a different type of numbers